# Ruby On Rails Home Page Custom Default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set my custom homepage as my default when I open my localhost ruby on rails . I followed about two answers to questions on here and this tutorial http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/static-pages-ruby-rails . I am also trying to write my code in notepad ++ so that it could show on my web browser(Google Chrome). If someone could help me with the tutorial I am trying to follow on team tree house or give me another answer , I would really appreciate it . Thanks

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
root 'Welcome#code'

# Example of regular route:
#   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

# Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
#   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

# Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
#   resources :products

# Example resource route with options:
#   resources :products do
#     member do
#       get 'short'
#       post 'toggle'
#     end
#
#     collection do
#       get 'sold'
#     end
#   end

# Example resource route with sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments, :sales
#     resource :seller
#   end

# Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments
#     resources :sales do
#       get 'recent', on: :collection
#     end
#   end

# Example resource route with concerns:
#   concern :toggleable do
#     post 'toggle'
#   end
#   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
#   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

# Example resource route within a namespace:
#   namespace :admin do
#     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
#     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
#     resources :products
#   end
end
```

Comment: This should be your routes issue. in file: `config/routes`, you should have the following: `root "pages#show", page: "home"`. If that doesn't work, please edit your post and show what your code looks like in the routes file. Also, try typing `rake routes` in your terminal (within your projects root directory) and copy paste that in your edit

Comment: @philipyoo I just put in my routes.rb file Where do I put the code you told me to put ?

Comment: Cool beans, now in there, replace `root 'Welcome#code'` with `root "pages#show", page: "home"`. Also make sure you have already created this page: `app/views/pages/about.html.erb`. Once you did that, try starting up localhost again and check it out

Comment: I don't have app/views/pages/about.html.erb . All I have is C:\ruby\rails\Interface\app\views\layouts and when i click layouts , it shows me application.html.erb .

Comment: Ok cool, so we need to create the `about.html.erb` file inside the `app/views/pages` folder. Once you create that, inside the file, add any html, for example: ` <h2>Home Page</h2>`

Comment: I don't have a views/pages folder only a views and when I click views it says application.html.erb

Comment: Ah I see, do you by chance have google+ ? I think it might be better to chat via chatroom. Or skype?

Comment: Yes I do . brandont264@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "welcome#code"

#app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def code
  end
end

#app/views/welcome/code.html.erb
Hello world!
```

This will give you the ability to browse to `localhost:3000` ([`lvh.me:3000`](https://reinteractive.net/posts/199-developing-and-testing-rails-applications-with-subdomains)) and have the contents of `welcome#code` displayed.

---

As an extension (since you're a beginner), any "random" methods in your controllers *should* be put into `ApplicationController`. This way, you negate having to add an unnecessary `WelcomeController`...

```
#config/routes.rb
root "application#welcome"

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def welcome
  end
end

#app/views/application/welcome.html.erb
Hello world.
```